# Php not sending with headers

Tags: php

Hello, I am having trouble with some of my code. Even my teacher can't help me, and I don't know where else to go. When my foreach loop is activated and the password and username are the same as the hard-coded strings, it is still redirecting to loginerror.php. When I remove header("Location: loginerror.php"), it functions fine. Why is the last line of my code still activated, when it should load a new page?

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<header></header>
<body>
<form action="login.php" Method="post">
 Username: <input type="text" name="Username"> </br></br>
 Password: <input type="password" name="Password"> </br></br>
 <input type="submit" value="Login"></br></br>
 </form>
<?php 


 $username=$_POST["Username"];
 $password=$_POST["Password"];
 if($username == NULL){print("Enter a Username please");}
 else {


  $users= array
  (
 "Bourne"=>"postcode",
  "Unidan"=>"pincode",
  "yoda"=>"sith"
   );

  foreach($users as $user=>$password_value)
  {
  if(($user==$username)&&($password_value==$password))
  {
  $_SESSION['login?']=1;
  header("Location: calculation.php");
  }}
  $_SESSION['login?']=0;
  header("Location: loginerror.php");
  }

  ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: `"Even my teacher cant help me"` - I highly recommend finding a better teacher.

Comment: Your teacher is clueless... your header() calls will NOT work because you've output a full html document before the header() code is ever reached.

Comment: Those that can't, teach.

Comment: @MarcB with the exception of if output buffering is turned on, which it likely is given that he's getting redirected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the PHP Docs:

> Remember that **header()** must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before **header()** is called.

Reference: [Header Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Move your PHP code to the top of the file and it should solve your problem:

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    $username=$_POST["Username"];
    $password=$_POST["Password"];
   if ($username == NULL) {
       print("Enter a Username please");
   } else {
       $users= array("Bourne"=>"postcode", "Unidan"=>"pincode", "yoda"=>"sith");

       foreach($users as $user=>$password_value) {
           if(($user==$username)&&($password_value==$password)) {
               $_SESSION['login?']=1;
               header("Location: calculation.php");
               // Add this to terminate the script immediately and redirect.
               exit();
           }
       }
       $_SESSION['login?']=0;
       header("Location: loginerror.php");
       // Add this to terminate the script immediately and redirect.
       exit();
    }
?>
<html>
<header></header>
<body>
    <form action="login.php" Method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="Username"> </br></br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="Password"> </br></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login"></br></br>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Header's must be sent before any output, ***including*** HTML output.

Answer (score 0):

`exit` so no other code is executed after the redirect:

```
header("Location: calculation.php");
exit;
```

Comment: You can't send the headers after you've already begun sending additional output...

Comment: Really?  That's why it's redirecting to `loginerror.php`?  Didn't say this is great code, I was answering why it continues to redirect to `loginerror.php`.  Most likely output buffering is on in `php.ini`.

Comment: Just adding `exit;` would solve the problem though. The `headers()` should be output first...

Answer (score 0):

Changing your code structure to something like this may help you.

Note: this is not code correction.

```
<?php 
session_start();

$username=$_POST["Username"];
$password=$_POST["Password"];
if($username == NULL){
    print("Enter a Username please");
}
else {
        $users= array
        (
        "Bourne"=>"postcode",
        "Unidan"=>"pincode",
        "yoda"=>"sith"
        );

        foreach($users as $user=>$password_value)
        {
            if(($user==$username)&&($password_value==$password))
            {
                $_SESSION['login?']=1;
                header("Location: calculation.php");
                exit;
            }
        }
        $_SESSION['login?']=0;
        header("Location: loginerror.php");
        exit;
}
?>
<html>
<header></header>
<body>
<form action="login.php" Method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="Username"> </br></br>
Password: <input type="password" name="Password"> </br></br>
<input type="submit" value="Login"></br></br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like it was mentioned prior. You are already outputting prior to sending headers.
You need to wrap this in a conditional or have a second script checking the password.

You could wrap the code in if/else $_POST as well as break operation in foreach after the condition was met.